# Найти ошибку в листинге программы Borland

Tags: borland, c++

Выдает ошибку в 10 и 13 строках!
Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку!!!

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <string.h>

zapis rez; //ЇҐаҐ¬Ґ­­ п ¤«п еа ­Ґ­Ёп ®¤­®© § ЇЁбЁ - ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ!(иероглифы в блокноте выражены русскими буквами)

void main(void)
struct zapis*A { - И ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ!

char vybor = 0;

char f_name[20];

unsigned i, n;

char *str;

  while( vybor!='g') {

    cout << endl << "‚лЎҐаЁвҐ ­Ґ®Ўе®¤Ё¬®Ґ ¤Ґ©бвўЁҐ:" << endl;
    cout << "[a] ‘®§¤ ­ЁҐ бЇа ў®з­ЁЄ  (‚ў®¤ ¤ ­­ле)" << endl;
    cout << "[b] ‚лў®¤ бЇа ў®з­ЁЄ  б Ї®¬®ймо Ї®в®Є®ўле Є« бб®ў п§лЄ  ‘++" << endl;
    cout << "[c] “¤ «Ґ­ЁҐ § ЇЁбЁ" << endl;
    cout << "[d] ‘®авЁа®ўЄ  Ї® бва®Є®ў®¬г Ї®«о ¬Ґв®¤®¬ 'Їг§ламЄ '" << endl;
    cout << "[e] ‘®еа ­Ґ­ЁҐ бЇа ў®з­ЁЄ  ў д ©« б Ї®¬®ймо Ї®в®Є®ўле Є« бб®ў C++" << endl;
    cout << "[f] ЋвЄалвЁҐ бЇа ў®з­ЁЄ  Ё§ д ©«  б Ї®¬®ймо Ї®в®Є®ўле Є« бб®ў C++" << endl;
    cout << "[g] ‚ле®¤ Ё§ Їа®Ја ¬¬л" << endl;
    cout << "‚ и ўлЎ®а: ";

    cin >> vybor;
    switch(vybor) {

    case 'a': //б®§¤ Ґ¬ бЇа ў®з­ЁЄ ­  n н«Ґ¬Ґ­в®ў Ё ўў®¤Ё¬ Ёе б Є« ўЁ вгал
      cout << "‚ўҐ¤ЁвҐ зЁб«® н«Ґ¬Ґ­в®ў: ";
      cin >> n;
      if (renew(n)==0) {
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
      vvod(i);
    }
      }
      break;

    case 'b': //ўлў®¤ бЇа ў®зЁ­Є  б Ї®¬®ймо Ї®в®Є®ўле Є« бб®ў ‘++
      show();
      break;

    case 'c': //г¤ «Ґ­ЁҐ § ЇЁбЁ
      cout << "‚ўҐ¤ЁвҐ ь г¤ «пҐ¬®© § ЇЁбЁ: ";
      cin >> i;
      remove(i);
      show();
      break;

    case 'd': //б®авЁа®ўЄ  Ї® Ї®«о бва®Є®ў®Ј® вЁЇ  ¬Ґв®¤®¬ "Їг§ламЄ "
      sort_a_p();
      show();
      break;

    case 'e': //б®еа ­Ґ­ЁҐ бЇа ў®з­ЁЄ ў д ©« б Ї®¬®ймо Ї®в®Є®ўле Є« бб®ў ‘++
      cout << "‚ўҐ¤ЁвҐ Ё¬п д ©« : ";
      scanf("%s", f_name);
      save(f_name);
      break;

    case 'f': //§ Јаг¦ Ґ¬ бЇа ў®з­ЁЄ Ё§ д ©«  б Ї®¬®ймо Ї®в®Є®ўле Є« бб®ў C++
      cout << "‚ўҐ¤ЁвҐ Ё¬п д ©« : ";
      scanf("%s", f_name);
      load(f_name);
      show();
      break;

    case 'g': //ўле®¤Ё¬ Ё§ Їа®Ја ¬¬л
      return;

    default:
      cout << "ЌҐ®Ўе®¤Ё¬® ўўҐбвЁ ЎгЄўг Ё§ ¬Ґ­о" << endl;
      cout << "‚ и ўлЎ®а: ";
    }
    vybor = 0;
    getchar();//Ѓ«®ЄЁагҐ¬ Ї®б«Ґ¤­Ё© ­ ¦ вл© ўў®¤
  }
  return;

}
```

Comment: @Svetik, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: А main, который void?

Answer (score 1):

[[@Svetik](/users/24042/svetik)](/users/24042/svetik): Очевидно, компилятор не видит описание типа данных `zapis`. (Никогда, никогда не пользуйтесь транслитом в идентификаторах! Компьютер это может и съест, а вот коллеги-программисты...)